# how to identify broken binding using UI5 diagnostics

Tags: sapui5

[Step 30: Debugging Tools](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/1ff250c2038849f5991209f7e6c36f1f) of the UI5 documentation introduces the diagnostics, which can be accessed through the ctrl-alt-shift-S keycombo.

After deliberately inserting an error in a path, I've tried navigating to the binding info in the control tree as instructed:
[image]

I'm supposed to be able to *see that the binding path of the number attribute is **marked** as invalid*

It cannot possibly rely on me spotting the typo because that would imply already knowing what the error is in the first place.

Can anybody explain how exactly I should do that?

Additionally:

- Chrome 84.0 or Firefox 79.0, same results.
- tried the online version from the official demo kit as well as my own localhost copy

Comment: Must be a bug. I remember seeing the _invalid_ mark there when I started learning UI5. Time to report on GitHub again!

Comment: If you have a "known working" version to compare, by all means please do. Otherwise I can do that, just let me know.

Comment: Done: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2996

Comment: Wonderful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [fix](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/6b6472115f726fb18b899c8ec5a7d45b3100c91a) is now in the master branch of UI5. If you run the downloaded sample with
`https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js`, we can see the invalid binding path indication:

> ```
> ExTendedPrice (invalid)
> ```

[image: UI5 support ControlTree issue fixed (https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2996)]